# Cannot use camera on iPhone when run with Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am running a very simple script to access the camera. It works with the webcam on my laptop but it gives me a white screen when I run it on my iPhone

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {

    public WebCamTexture mCamera = null;
    public GameObject plane;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        Application.RequestUserAuthorization(UserAuthorization.WebCam);
        Debug.Log ("Script has been started");
        plane = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player");

        mCamera = new WebCamTexture ();
        plane.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = mCamera;
        mCamera.Play ();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }
}
```

When I build and run, Unity fires up XCode, where I also update info.plist so it asks for permission to access the camera

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution (this help):

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/706142/openstart-device-camera-in-unity3d-app-using-c-scr.html

Comment: I actually used that :(

Comment: May be this bug your version of unity? What your used version unity?

Comment: I actually figured it out. I had to get rid of the light. Thanks though.